# Configuring Chromium Browser to load multiple plugins from /etc/chromium-browser/default file

Tags: linux-mint, chrome

How can you configure Chromium Browser to load multipl plugins (specifically; type NPAPI)?. I edited /etc/chromium-browser/default to add the pepperflash from google-chrome (CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libpepflashplayer.so" and it is working. Now I need to add two more plugins for VMware Web Client that are not detected by default. The plugins are located in the chromium plugins folder. I appreciate any help on the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding:

```
--load-plugin=/path/to/plugin1,/path/to/plugin2
```

to your `CHROMIUM_FLAGS`

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches provides a useful reference for the command line options.